# Can someone find my syntax/logic error for 'unknown attribute' when creating seed method for a many to many join table in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, foreign-keys, join

The project is to build a web-app which I will use to log and track my strength training sessions. One of the tables/models is a join table linking exercises and trained bodyparts.

Here is the migration for the exercise table:

```
# migration: successfully creates the join table
class CreateExerciseBodyparts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :exercise_bodyparts do |t|
      t.references :exercise, foreign_key: true
      t.references :bodypart, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the seed data for the table:

```
# seed data snippet: no syntax errors here
def exercise_bodyparts_list
  return [
    {
      name: "Barbell Back Squats",
      bodyparts: ["Quads","Hamstrings","Adductors","Abductors","Glutes","Lower Back","Abs"]
    },
    {
      name: "Barbell Biceps Curls ~0°",
      bodyparts: ["Biceps","Forearms"]
    },
    {
      name: "Barbell Biceps Curls ~45°",
      bodyparts: ["Biceps","Forearms"]
    },
    #(...)
  ]
end
```

Here is my seed method to populate the DB:

```
# seed method: where the error comes...
exercise_bodyparts_list.each do |ex_body|
  ex_body[:bodyparts].each do |bodypart|
    ExerciseBodypart.create!(
      exercise: Exercise.find_by_name(ex_body[:name]),
      bodypart: Bodypart.find_by_name(bodypart)
      )
  end
end
```

Here is the error message:

```
# error message:
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'exercise' for ExerciseBodypart.
```

Comment: You do not need `return` keyword inside method  `exercise_bodyparts_list`

Comment: I know that Ruby has implicite returns, but I use it for my own practices to explicitly name the return.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know exact reason but it was working for me inside `rake` task in `rails-3` but failed for `rails-5` while updating application to higher version.

I suggest you try following, following worked for me,

```
exercise_id: Exercise.find_by_name(ex_body[:name]).id
```

Comment: Hi there - it is a funny thing.  I know that this solution should work, and I don't know why I am going to be stubborn about it, but I am going to use another solution - answered below.  I thank you for your effort and advice!

Answer (score 0):

I received advice from another Ruby developer who said that I ought to be naming the relationship nature in the model with `belongs_to`

I indeed did that and the logic works ok.

My model looks like this:

```
class ExerciseBodypart < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :exercise
  belongs_to :bodypart
end
```

Lo and behold, this was the key. This espressed relationship in the model doesn't exist in my other project; however I suspect that the relationship is taken from the connection of other models - as it is a more complicated database with many more models.

Comment: I am surprised, of course `exercise: Exercise.find_by_name(ex_body[:name])` should work with association provided. I did not know you did not have associations defined. I had association still it failed for higher version So I provided keys. I do not know reason but I found alternative which was needed only in rake. Glad you solved!